# How to get the default region for azure subscription through Python sdk

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

I am using Python SDK for azure. And want to know the default region for my subscription using the sdk.
Is there any method exposed my Python sdk for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by default region for your subscription?

Comment: I mean, I want to give my subscription id as input, and want to know what is the region of that subscription which was set while creating the subscription

Comment: I would not know that a subscription has a default region. Resource groups have a default location.